# numpy got installed in Python3.5 but not in Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.6

I have both Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 on my laptop. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I used `pip3` to install `numpy`. It is working with Python3.5 but not with Python3.6. Please help.

Comment: Using conda distribution and environments might make your life easier when you want to have multiple python versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

To install via pip for specific python version use:

```
    py -(python-version) -m pip install numpy
```

in your case

```
   py -3.6 -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Python is Python 3.6:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Now install with:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

This will run the `pip` for the current Python the option `-m` imports the module `pip` and runs it as it would be `pip` as command line app.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment since I don't the rep.

If your default python is 3.5 when you check `python --version`, the way to go would be to find the location of the python executable for the desired version (here 3.6).
cd to that folder and then run the command given by Mike.

Comment: so you have to locate the binary first.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Linux. I did not understand this "so you have to locate the binary first"